# Make a really simple gallery structure

Tags: gallery

The default gallery structure of WordPress is really tortuous:

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery...">
    <dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon">
            <a title="01Exam" href="bar">
                <img title="then my image" src="foo.jpg">
            </a>
        </dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Can you help me to output a simple list of images just like:

```
<ul class="gallery-item">
    <li>
        <img title="then my image" src="foo.jpg">
    <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I found how to change default `<dl>` and `<dt>` using `[gallery itemtag="div" icontag="span"]` but not how to remove it.

Comment: There's several related questions shown to the right(under the "Related" heading) that would of provided ample solutions to this question, just an FYI.

Answer (score 5):

Use your own `gallery` shortcode handler - something like this in your `functions.php`:

```
function __my_gallery_shortcode( $attr )
{
     // render the gallery the way you want it
}
add_shortcode( 'gallery', '__my_gallery_shortcode' );
```

To get you started, you could just copy the code from the [default handler `gallery_shortcode()`](http://wpseek.com/source/wp/latest/wp-includes/media.php.source.html#l747), and edit as you require.

Comment: Sadly there's really no better way to do this...